# Google + AFOAuth2Client

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, afnetworking

I'm trying to login on Google + through AFOAuth2Client (AFNetworking extension).
I wrote this code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/"];
AFOAuth2Client *oauthClient = [AFOAuth2Client  clientWithBaseURL:url clientID:@"MY_ID" secret:@"MY_SECRET"];

[oauthClient authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:@"/o/oauth2/token"
                                     parameters:@{@"scope": @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", @"response_type" : @"code", @"redirect_uri" : @"https://www.domain.com/oauth2callback"}
                                        success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
        NSLog(@"I have a token! %@", credential.accessToken);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

But the error block is called with an invalid_request (Error 400).
Am I missing something? (A missing parameter?)

Comment: did you fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please Look into the [OAuth2 Doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) carefully, The Parameters in your code is wrong. scope should be openid or email, and there're other parameters missing.